# How to add images dynamically in Ajax SlideShowExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am creating a Slideshow using Slideshow extender dynamically.
My web service code is :-

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public static AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] GetSlides()
{
    AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] slides = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[tblData.Tables[Count_w].Rows.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < tblData.Tables[Count_w].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = tblData.Tables[Count_w].Rows[i];
        slides[i] = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide(dr["imgurl"].ToString(), dr["header"].ToString(), dr["descr"].ToString());
    }
    Count_w++;
    return slides;
}
```

Any clues as to why this is happening. 
I have tried of including hardcoding in the web service and it works.
Working code :-

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public static AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] GetSlides()
{
    return new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] { 
        new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("Help/1.png", "Add new server", "Login on server"),
        new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("Help/2.png", "Add new server", "Login success"),
        new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("Help/3.png", "Add new server", "Create new user"),
        new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("Help/4.png", "Add new server", "Test user")};
    return slides;
}
```

Can any one tell me why dynamic population not working.
Where both methods returns same result.

Comment: try this http://forums.asp.net/t/1860190.aspx/1?how+to+show+images+stored+in+sql+database+on+ajax+SlideShowExtender

Comment: Did you tried to set breakpoint at `return slides;` line and check `slides` array?

Comment: Yes both Services gives same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by removing extra slashes.

### Change this

```
dr["imgurl"].ToString()
```

### By this

```
dr["imgurl"].ToString().Replace("\\", "/")
```

### Updated Code

```
[WebMethod]
public AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] GetSlides(DataTable dt)
{
    AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] slides = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[dt.Rows.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
        slides[i] = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide(dr["imgurl"].ToString().Replace("\\", "/"), dr["header"].ToString(), dr["descr"].ToString());
    }
    return slides;
}
```